# Content of Dialog dims as well as background

Tags: android, dialog, android-camera

I have a custom dialog activity containing a camera preview inside of a FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
```

When the dialog is brought up, the background is dimmed like normal, but the FrameLayout is dimmed as well.

I tried removing the dim with a custom style, but that also removed the dimming behind the dialog.

```
<style name="Theme.DoNotDim" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Is there any way to stop the dimming of the FrameLayout while keeping the normal background dimming?